# Get following data between two dates

Tags: magento-1.9

I would like to get the following data between two dates:

- Total number of orders
- Total revenue excl
- Profit excl VAT
- VAT Total revenue incl VAT
- Total profit excl VAT

I'm trying the following query but seems not correct to me.

```
$from = date('Y-m-d');
$to = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-2 year'));
$query = "SELECT SUM(orders_count) AS orders_count,
                 SUM(total_qty_ordered)            AS total_qty_ordered,
                 SUM(total_qty_invoiced)           AS total_qty_invoiced,
                 SUM(total_income_amount)          AS total_income_amount,
                 SUM(total_revenue_amount)         AS total_revenue_amount,
                 SUM(total_profit_amount)          AS total_profit_amount,
                 SUM(total_invoiced_amount)        AS total_invoiced_amount,
                 SUM(total_paid_amount)            AS total_paid_amount,
                 SUM(total_refunded_amount)        AS total_refunded_amount,
                 SUM(total_tax_amount)             AS total_tax_amount,
                 SUM(total_tax_amount_actual)      AS total_tax_amount_actual,
                 SUM(total_shipping_amount)        AS total_shipping_amount,
                 SUM(total_shipping_amount_actual) AS total_shipping_amount_actual,
                 SUM(total_discount_amount)        AS total_discount_amount,
                 SUM(total_discount_amount_actual) AS total_discount_amount_actual,
                 SUM(total_canceled_amount)        AS total_canceled_amount
          FROM sales_order_aggregated_created
          WHERE period <= $from AND period >= $to";
```

The above query is what I'm using to get total numbers of orders, Total Revenue and Profit, but I'm not getting the idea on how to calculate taxes.

Also, I'm not sure about using the `sales_order_aggregated_created` table.

Comment: and date_created between CAST('2018-09-15' AS DATE) AND CAST('2018-09-28' AS DATE);

Comment: try this above one, as static query, if works then pass var